# I want to hide upper left icon of material-ui Appbar. Can somebody tell me how can I hide it?

Tags: material-ui

I want to hide upper left icon of material-ui Appbar. Can somebody tell me how can I hide it? because I am not implementing anything on click of that icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it saids on the docs, you have two options, you can use for example an empty react component like below on the iconElementLeft property or also iconClassNameLeft

`<AppBar iconElementLeft={(<div />)} />`

See more here: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar